# How to load contract from address- remix?

Tags: remix, contract-invocation

Hi I just found that remix added "`Load contract from address`" option. So I tried to load contract from address "`0x67601d7a7cbbD77368785122c508503f168B1dAa`" . You can see this contract is in function in https://www.stateofthedapps.com/dapps/cute-kitty-farm . I connected to main network using `meta mask` but it is not loading any contract. Instead it just deploys my own contract. How can I load contract from this address? Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This process works as follows:

- You must **compile the same exact code that the contract** you are trying to load.
- Once the compile succeeds, **you have to be on the same network that the contract is, by setting your MetaMask account propperly**.
- The last thing to do is **paste the contract address on the option: `Load from address:`** and you'll get it on remix to interact with it.

I've seen that you're doing that on the main net. **If you want to test things like that i highly recommend you to search for the same contract on a testnet and then, try to load it**. Cause if you deploy by error on the main net, the joke will cost you real money.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I need to have exact same of the contract. I thought it will show just the output of compiled contract. Thank you for your help.

Comment: why is this necessary??

Comment: Connecting to the same network is necessary to load the contract. I think compiling the same contract is needed to get the ABI. Accessing a deployed contract requires Address and ABI.