# How to deploy smart contract with visible source code (etherscan)?

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a contract to the rinkeby (hope that thats the network to use for beta testing). 
Deploying worked with the command `truffle migrate --reset -f 2 --network rinkeby`.

Unfortunately, I tried to access the contract through etherscan and I only can see the bytecode. How should I add the source code to etherscan so that it is possible to interact with the contract on etherscan? Is there a way to do it automatically?

Thanks a lot for any hint!

Comment: https://etherscan.io/verifyContract2

Comment: Thanks for the link. That seems to be what I'm looking for :). Do you know any framework which can verify the Contract automatically ?

Comment: I don't know of one, no. It's likely there are too many steps included to be able to reliably automate the process. (Someone else might know of something.)

Comment: Just tried it with https://github.com/nomiclabs/truffle-flattener but seems something ist still wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have Etherscan show the code associated with a deployed contract, you'll need to go through the verification process:

https://etherscan.io/verifyContract2

However, to interact with your contract you'll probably want to use Remix (https://remix.ethereum.org), and load the contract from the deployed address:

[How to load contract from address- remix?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49376/how-to-load-contract-from-address-remix)

Comment: Any Idea how to find the matched compiler. I just tried the first step and failed. In my code I have: pragma solidity ^0.4.22;  So choosed v0.22. commit but there are many versions..

Comment: It should be the one without `nightly` in the name, so `v.0.4.22+commit.4cb486ee`.

Comment: Thanks yes it worked. Could deploy the contract with sources. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it worked :-)